# What pepper varieties have the longest shelf-life?

Tags: peppers

I'm looking for pepper plant recommendations.

Which pepper varieties keep the longest, or for a really long time (after being picked, unrefrigerated, without being dried)? I'm hoping for 2+ weeks wonder-peppers. They can be hot or sweet.

Edit: I'm wanting these peppers for plant-breeding purposes. I'm not looking for techniques to get all peppers to last longer. Even if you know a pepper that keeps slightly longer than average, that's still better than nothing.

Comment: Would this be better on [cooking.se], like your question about the shelf life of sharkfin melons, since it's about the pepper as a food, not about growing them?

Comment: @NiallC. I don't think it would be better or worse, particularly, but it is for gardening purposes (e.g. genetics for breeding; not just so I can get any old pepper to last). It is for plant recommendations, which fits the help center (while the Shark Fin Melon question wasn't about recommendations).

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on climate - more than the variety imho. Here in North Texas I have no problem with two weeks, assuming the peppers weren't picked when very ripe. However in somewhere like New Mexico where it is much drier, you can just leave them out to dry naturally. They hang them up on strings, etc to dry.

Comment: Insightful answer. However, it's not quite what I'm looking for, but still good to know. I edited my answer to reflect that better. Sorry about the fuss! Thanks! :)